# Simplify multiple optional filters in Django

Tags: python, django

I posted a question a few hour ago and it was marked as duplicated (it was not) and I couldn't find my answer here so I had to find it in an other place.

Here was the question:
How to simplify many optional filters in django. For example:
model = "some_rare_model"

```
if max_speed:
   if year:
       if color:
           cars = Car.objects.filter(model=model,max_speed=max_speed,year=year,color__icontains=color)
       else:
           car = Car.objects.filter(model=model,max_speed=max_speed,year=year)
   else:
       if color:
           cars = Car.objects.filter(model=model,max_speed=max_speed,color__icontains=color)
       else:
           cars = Car.objects.filter(model=model,max_speed=max_speed)
else:
   if year:
       if color:
           cars = Car.objects.filter(model=model,year=year,color__icontains=color)
       else:
           car = Car.objects.filter(model=model,year=year)
   else:
       if color:
           cars = Car.objects.filter(model=model,color__icontains=color)
       else:
           cars = Car.objects.filter(model=model)
```

How to simplify that code?

Answer (score 2):

Although passing a dictionary is a good approach, another is a shown below. Remember querysets are not evaluated until they are used, and can be changed as much as you want.
So you could do something like this

```
cars = Car.objects.filter(model=model)
if max_speed:
    cars = cars.filter(max_speed=max_speed)
if year:
    cars = cars.filter(year=year)
if color:
    cars = cars.filter(color__icontains=color)
```

You can do as many as you like. And it's very verbose.

**Edit:** I notice you have also mentioned that querysets are lazy. I'll still leave this answer here as it may help someone in the future.

Comment: Both have good approach. The difference is that the first one will evaluate all the filters at the same time, this one will evaluate first max_speed and after will filter the results by the others parameters. The other good thing about using dictionary is that you can easily modify the filters and construct new ones without using to many conditions. My answer was intended for that purpose.... How ever for the example your answer is better.

Answer (score 1):

To simplify that code you can use a dictionary.

For example, if you want to filter those cars with a color that contains "blue":

```
cars = Car.object.filter(**{'color__icontains': 'blue'})
```

So, in order to filter color, year and max_speed if given we can build something like this:

```
filters = {"model":'some_rare_model'}
if color:
    filters['color__icontains'] = color
if year:
    filters['year'] = year
if max_speed:
    filters['max_speed'] = max_speed
cars = Car.objects.filter(**filters)
```

8 lines of code compared with 24 is a big advance and is also more clear. You could even create a function that will return a dictionary with all the keys and values from for example the queryset in a url, making the code even shorter.

You can also keep filtering those model and even it will only call the database once ([query sets are lazy](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/queries/#querysets-are-lazy))

Original [answer to my question](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/402159-simplify-multiple-conditioned-filters-query-in-django/page__gopid__2311659&#entry2311659):

Hoppe this helps someone in the future.

Comment: Very nice @adrian. Very nice. I was about to write the same answer as you. Way to go!